# Laurent expansion of $\sqrt{1+x^2}-x$ as 1/x, 1/x^2 ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given function:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}-x$$

I need to expand it as powers of $\frac 1x$

I tried:

$$f(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}$$

Then, binomial expansion of $(1+x^2)^{1/2}=1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\cdots$

I got:

$$f(x)=\frac {1}{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\cdots}$$

Then, I tried to equal:
$$f(x)=a_0+\frac {a_1}{x}+\frac{a_2}{x^2}+\frac{a_3}{x^3}+\cdots$$

So, if I combine them:
$$1=(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\cdots)*(a_0+\frac {a_1}{x}+\frac{a_2}{x^2}+\frac{a_3}{x^3}+\cdots)$$

Can you help me to finish it, or suggest better way?

Comment: It's not called "Taylor" expansion, but instead "Laurent" expansion.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = x \underbrace{\left(\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{x^2}} - 1\right)}_{g(x)}$$
Now $$g(x)= -1 + 1 + \dfrac{1/2}{x^2} + \dfrac{1/2 \times(-1/2)}{2! \cdot x^4} + \dfrac{1/2 \times(-1/2) \times (-3/2)}{3! \cdot x^6}  \mp \cdots$$
Hence,
$$f(x) = \dfrac1{2x} - \dfrac1{8x^3} + \dfrac1{16x^5} \mp$$